# Why I cant instantiate 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder?

Tags: apache-spark, hive

Im working on ssh server where I load spark through the following command:

```
module load spark/2.3.0
```

I want to create a Hive table to save my DataFrame partitions into this table.

my code `mycode.py` is the following:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    warehouse_location = abspath('spark-warehouse')
    conf = (SparkConf()
    .setMaster("local[*]")
    .setAppName(appName)
    .set("spark.default.parallelism", 128)
    .set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 128)
    )

    spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouse_location).enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
    sc = spark.sparkContext
    sqlContext = SQLContext(sparkContext = sc)
    sc.stop()
```

This code generates the following exception:

```
    py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o41.sessionState.
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder':
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$instantiateSessionState(SparkSession.scala:1064)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sessionState$2.apply(SparkSession.scala:141)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sessionState$2.apply(SparkSession.scala:140)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:140)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState(SparkSession.scala:137)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:235)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$instantiateSessionState(SparkSession.scala:1059)
        ... 16 more
```

How can I solve this issue? where is my error please? Note that I run the above code using `spark-submit mycode.py`. I dont know if i need to add any parameter to this commond

Answer (score 0):

For my case, this happens because Spark missing Hive dependencies

What I did is to add Jars to Pyspark Dependencies

```
submit_args = '--packages org.apache.spark:spark-hive_2.11:2.4.6 pyspark-shell'
if 'PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS' not in os.environ:
    os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = submit_args
else:
    os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] += submit_args
```